# Nginx configuration catch uuid route

Tags: regex, nginx

I need to catch route in my nginx conf:
`http://example.com/media/{uuid}`
I'm trying:

```
location ~ "/media/([a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})" {
// ...
}
```

Uuid regexp is ok: https://regex101.com/r/bXMmFP/1
But it's not working on Nginx side. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the forwards slashes so that they are not recognized as PCRE separators:

```
location ~ "\/media\/([a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})" {
```

https://regex101.com/r/TRnSPu/1

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
location ~* "^/media/[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}\b-[0-9a-f]{12}$/"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).